# Unable to get launch.d to run a python script on OSX Catalina

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, homebrew

I have a simple python script that loads jantman's xfinity usage script to save my current Comcast usage to a file (that I will later process). This file works exactly as expected via the terminal command `python get-comcast-usage.py`. That file looks like this (as I said, it's simple):

```
import os
import json

import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)

os.environ['XFINITY_USER'] = 'phillip.gooch@comcast.net';
os.environ['XFINITY_PASSWORD'] = 'Heu7tZyf/@6tPHT';

from xfinity_usage.xfinity_usage import XfinityUsage
usageScraper = XfinityUsage(os.environ['XFINITY_USER'], os.environ['XFINITY_PASSWORD'], browser_name='chrome-headless')
usage = usageScraper.run()

with open('usage.txt', 'w') as save:
    json.dump(usage, save)
```

The output of path was just to try and figure out why it's not working, see when I try to have the launch.d run this script every hour (setup through Lingon X). I set up the following command to run every hour:

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/my-account-name/Development/internet-gauge-cluster/get-comcast-usage.py
```

When I run that for testing I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/still-just-me/Development/internet-gauge-cluster/get-comcast-usage.py", line 11, in <module>
    from xfinity_usage.xfinity_usage import XfinityUsage
ImportError: No module named xfinity_usage.xfinity_usage
```

It's installed with pip per the instructions on the repo (https://github.com/jantman/xfinity-usage) and works fine when I'm running it from the terminal myself, but it keeps erring when I test. It seems like I have different path between the two sources, mostly the same but there are a few extras I get when loading locally that I don't get from the test error.

I imagine all I have to do to get this working is update the right path information, however I don't know where the right place to update that would be. Python on mac seems kinda like a mess of version 2/3, built-in/brew, and differences between versions of OSX and I just don't know enough about how python is installed and operated to fix the right thing (I hardly use python, but am comfortable with the language, just not the setup and weird configuration stuff).

I'm sure this is far easier to fix that I've made it out to be, but at this point I'm not sure I haven't completely botched Python on my system. If that is the case whats the best way to get rid of all of it and reinstall a new single version?

Comment: I hope those are not your actual login credentials, if so, please change/delete.

Comment: Run `type python` in Terminal to see which Python you are using. Then make sure you use the same one in Lingon X.

Comment: It's not my real password.
typing `python` in terminal gives me 2.7.16 but I have no idea how to get the version launch.d is using. That is probably the problem however, I'd be happy to remove all versions of python and just installing one single version from brew but I haven't looked into that yet, I was hoping for a less destructive solution.